# how to generate two reports on every single a4 page using while loop in php

Tags: php, html, mysqli, page-break

I am working on a form which can generate several reports on a single click. These reports maybe in the hundreds so what I need to do is print only two reports on every single a4 page and after that the loop should jump to another page to print more reports. I just know the simple while loop is there anyone who can help me on this?

here is just the simple while loop which i know

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
/**the reports goes here**/

}
```

Comment: Just put a div with some class on condition. And give css `page-break-after:always` to it.

Comment: but how ??? that can be applied for a single report but here i want is two reports on a single page

Comment: That's why I mention `condition`. You need to put two reports in div using some condition.

Comment: so can u please provide me sum examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in comment, you need to combine two reports in a single div with css of page-break something like,

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 if($i % 2 == 0){
      echo "<div style='page-break-after:always'>"; 
 }
 /**the reports goes here**/
 if($i % 2 != 0){
      echo "</div>"; // Close div taking two reports in it.
 }
 $i++;
}
```